# How can I get a WSL window with full colour support in Windows GUI Emacs?

Tags: terminal, emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ansi-term

How can I get WSL to run in a window on Windows GUI Emacs?

The only way I can do it so far is to enter a subshell in either emacs shell or term cmd by entering the `wsl` command, and even then, there is no background ANSI coloring, though the foreground coloring appears to be working.

The following is an attempt at directly spawning a `wsl.exe` child process.

```lisp
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)

    (setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe")

    (defun run-wsl ()
        (interactive)
        (let ((shell-file-name "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"))
        (ansi-term "*wsl.exe*"))))
```

Error message under mode bar: `Spawning child process: Invalid argument`

---

Note:

I am asking how to get WSL in Emacs, not Emacs in WSL.